# GCP Ingress backend unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, ambassador

I have a gcp cluster with api services and I was using ambassador 1.9 for edge routing. Now we have decided to upgrade the ambassador to 2.3.2. So I follow the steps in ambassador docs for upgradation by parallelly running both ambassador versions. But after the process is finished the backend service is unhealthy, making the ingress down.

1. Multiple deployments with corresponding services.
2. Ambassador Edge Stack as API gateway
3. Ingress for exposing the edge stack service

I'm a beginner in both ambassador and stackoverflow, so please let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is add a backend config

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
name: ambassador-hc-config
spec:
# https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features
timeoutSec: 30
connectionDraining:
   drainingTimeoutSec: 30
logging:
   enable: true
   sampleRate: 1.0
healthCheck:
   checkIntervalSec: 10
   timeoutSec: 10
   port: 8877
   type: HTTP
   requestPath: /ambassador/v0/check_alive
```

add this yaml and add the annotation

```
cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "ambassador-hc-config"}'
```

to the ambassador/edge-stack service.